# Extra space (or missing) after a ref with a second digit in a bibitem

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I create my bibliography as follows but after the 10nth Ref i have an extra space on the first line or a missing space on the following lines. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you!

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
.
.
.
\bibitem{hulu}
Hulu,
\emph{Hulu Bandwidth Recommendations},
URL: \url{http://www.hulu.com/support/article/197541},
January, 2014.

\bibitem{itu-t_p800_1}
ITU-T,
\emph{Mean Opinion Score (MOS) Terminology},
ITU-T Recommendation P.800.1,
November, 2006.
.
.
.
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: extra space after a ref with a second digit in bibitem after the second line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `\begin{thebibliography}{}` should be the widest string ever used as a label. So you should change the 9 to 99, or even 999, to leave space.